# Select sum of multiple columns based on the conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to find addition of low_cvt,med_cvt and high_cvt based on the unique idCampaign. for example in the screenshot, idcampaign 3870576 is repeating twice and it's addition is 12.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r77Av.jpg

I am using following statement in select statement:

```
  CVT.low_cvt + CVT.med_cvt + CVT.high_cvt + CVT.other_cvt AS 'All CVT',
```

however, it is giving duplicate idcampaign.

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT column1` You can pull unique data with Distinct

Comment: The published statement will not produce duplicates - you need to add the rest of the statement, and table definition. nb questions should be self contained - linking to imugr is not helpful

Comment: Please, don't forget to accept the answer that fixed your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a query like this:

```
SELECT CVT.idcampaign,
       SUM(CVT.low_cvt+CVT.med_cvt+CVT.high_cvt+CVT.other_cvt) AS 'All CVT'
FROM Your_Table AS CVT
WHERE CVT.idcampaign = 3870576
GROUP BY CVT.idcampaign;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I was missing group by statement. Thanks very much